# Rails: Is there an else statement in if try(:current_order)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to have an else statement in if try()?

The else block will be ignored:

```
          <% if try(:current_order) %>
            <% if current_order.state != 'complete' && current_order.line_items.count > 0 %>
            <%= current_order.line_items.count %>
            <% end %>
            <% else %>
            <%= "&nbsp;".html_safe %>
          <% end %>
```

I want to achieve print out of `&nbsp;` if try(:current_order) fails.

UPDATE:

```
    <li class="icon icon-cart">
      <%= link_to spree.cart_path do %>
      <div class="cart">
        <%= image_tag("shopping_bag.png", class: 'shopping-bag') %>
        <span class="cart-items-count">
          <% if current_order %>
            <% if current_order.state != 'complete' && current_order.line_items.count > 0 %>
              <%= current_order.line_items.count %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            &nbsp;
          <% end %>
        </span>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </li>
```

I use this snippet in a header and when i open a static page where no current_order is available then i get:

```
NameError in Spree::Pages#show

undefined local variable or method `current_order' for #<#<Class:0x007fcd7636c090>:0x007fcd8770e0c0>
```

Is there an easy fix without using try?

Comment: You don't need to try on a variable use it if you are chaining the methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `try` here? Just use `current_order` itself:

```
<% if current_order %>
  <% if current_order.state != 'complete' && current_order.line_items.count > 0 %>
    <%= current_order.line_items.count %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  &nbsp;
<% end %>
```

If `current_order` is `nil` then `&nbsp;` will be shown.

For the record, `try` is used to avoid calling methods on `nil` (so e.g. `foo.try(:bar)` will return `nil` if `foo` is `nil`, whereas `foo.bar` will raise a `NoMethodError`). This is not relevant to your use case here, so you don't need `try`.

Comment: i use this snippet in my website header. when the snippet is used on a static page where no current_order is available i get with your attempt an error message:
"undefined local variable or method `current_order' "

Answer (score 1):

OK, probably there is a more elegant solution but this works:

```
<% if defined?(current_order) && !current_order.blank? %>
```

instead of `if current_order`

Answer (score 1):

`.try` an ActiveSupport utility for protecting against nil errors when calling a method on a variable that may be nil. It works here since the implicit subject is the view context but is not very idiomatic.

Instead you should be using `local_assigns[:current_order]` to check if a local variable is available to the view, partial or layout.

Lets start by cleaning this up.

`current_order.state != 'complete'` smells. Determining if a order is complete should not be done by the view!

```
class Order < SomeOtherClass

  # ...
  def complete?
    state == 'complete'
  end
end
```

We can then clean up the partial:

```
<% if local_assigns[:current_order] %>
  <% if !current_order.complete? &&  current_order.line_items.any? %>
    <%= current_order.line_items.size %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%# no order found %>
  <%= "&nbsp;".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Using `.size` instead of `.count` avoids doing a `COUNT` query if the records already have been loaded.

Comment: the result of <% if local_assigns[:current_order] %> is not equal to <% if defined?(current_order) && !current_order.blank? %>

Comment: No - `if local_assigns[:current_order]` will simply check if the local assign is nil. [`.blank?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) does quite a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `else` for `try`

You can check for the presence of `current_order`

```
<% if current_order.present? && current_order.state != 'complete' && current_order.line_items.count > 0 %>
  <%= current_order.line_items.count %>
<% else %>
  &nbsp;
<% end %>
```

Comment: This would raise `undefined local variable or method 'current_order'` on the first line. Try running `foo.present?` from the console. `present?` is used to test if a key in a hash or if a variable is nil. Not to check if a variable is defined.